# How can I restore /etc/nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

By mistake I have removed /etc/nginx directory in my ubuntu 11.10 PC. How can I restore the ngnix directory in /etc/nginx ?

I did these commands:

1. `sudo su`
2. `rm -rf /etc/nginx`

I want to get again /etc/nginx directory. how?

I tried this to re-install nginx:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get install nginx`

then it gives following

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree   

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nginx
```

How can i get full nginx software on ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: I had these error `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf’: and `dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (--configure):` No such file or directory` the below answer was useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 428, accepted):

To recreate it, first uninstall using purge to remove even configuration files and records:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
```

then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

If above doesn't work for you, you can also try using --force-confmiss option of dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_*.deb
```