# Nginx not working properly after update

Tags: nginx

Okay, so I had nginx 1.4.6 running on ubuntu 13.10 without any problems.

I tried to update nginx to 1.6.0 via this url (http://leftshift.io/upgrading-nginx-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-servers)

Now nginx is not running and not willing to start (no reaction at all). **nginx -v** gives "nginx: command not found" as a result. So looks like nginx can't be found.

I looked around here and on other sites, but wasn't able to find the solution. So, if anyone can.. plz do..

Comment: Are you sure you have a path for nginx?

Comment: **echo $PATH** gives me: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games". But how to check or set a path for nginx?

Comment: Result: "nginx: /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx". So should I then do **PATH=/etc/nginx/:$PATH"** or **PATH=/usr/share/nginx/:$PATH"** ?

Comment: Is that the one you will be running? Because like you two installations of nginx right now. Try sudo /usr/share/nginx and see if you instance is running.

Comment: As far as I can recall, I always worked in **/etc/nginx/**. "sudo /usr/share/nginx" & "sudo /etc/nginx" result in <sudo: /usr/share/nginx: command not found>.

Comment: Btw, "nginx -v" gives <nginx version: nginx/1.6.0> and "nginx -t" gives a succesfull test for </etc/nginx/nginx.conf>. But all commands with "service nginx ..." (like start, stop & status) are not responsive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68815/discussion-between-cbass-and-john-doe).

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

As this was a server without any active tools or software I decided to remove and reinstall nginx.
I used this answer: [How can I restore /etc/nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362967/how-can-i-restore-etc-nginx)

**QUOTE:**

To recreate it, first uninstall using purge to remove even configuration files and records:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full
```

then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

After these two commands, nginx was up and running again. I can now use my backup to upload the predefined .vhosts files to sites-enabled again.