# Restore complete nginx configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I´ve removed the Nginx service using purge command. After that I decided to remove manually the /etc/nginx directory to have it again with the default configuration. The problem is that after installing again Nginx, I don´t have the complete configuration of the server. I´ve tried the answer proposed here, [How can I restore /etc/nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362967/how-can-i-restore-etc-nginx) , seems to work, but I don´t have the complete configuration (sites-available, sites-enable and other paths are still measing).

Comment: What OS do you have? Try this if you have Debian/Ubuntu distro: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04. I have solved the problem including manually the lost directories, it is a solution but not the pretty one

Answer (score 0):

Next time you can do it with following command:

```
apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" nginx-full
```

to see what it goes to add to your system, you can run it with `--dry-run` option like this:

```
apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" nginx-full --dry-run
```